# Unity NGUI add new Sprite in Atlas and goes out wrong with offset Problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, atlas, ngui

im a client developer

my app uses NGUI in 2020.3.17 version in unity

i always have a problem..
when i have to add a new sprite in a Atlas and update
the atlas that i added new sprite goes wrong

not only the image that i added, every image in that atlas offset get messy
do you now any reason of this?

is there any reason with the file path??
the path is not in resource folder
because to minimize the app storage with using Asset Bundle

here's some image plz help...

before adding new image in this Atlas
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1whW.png)

after adding new image in this Atlas
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRvzZ.png)

file Atlas Path
Asset/Editor Default Resources/UI/Network
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxPtG.png)

Comment: Is there a reason all the assets are in the folder „Editor Default Resources“? Because that is a special file path and might cause the issue. What happens if you rename the folder name? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html

Answer (score 0):

If it is NGUI Atlas, you can drag and drop the text file created in TP Import.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).